# MySQL query to PHP string stop writing delimiter on last column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am kind of stuck and not sure where to even begin to fix this.  I have a MySQL query that is writing out the records to a string like this:

```
$values = mysql_query("SELECT Pointer AS Pointer, VNum AS Vnum FROM ".$table."");
$row = 0;
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_assoc($values)) 
{
  foreach($rowr as $name => $value)
  {
      $csv_output .= $value."|";
  }
      $csv_output .= "\n";
}
```

This works great EXCEPT the Vnum value ends up with a `|` appended to it like this:

> 10467|66|

I need to have the values written out like `10467|66` without the `|` delimiter after the Vnum value.  How do I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually if you are using `foreach`, the loop will continue until it reaches the last or the `NULL` value, so to handle the last char or |, you have to add a code to eliminate the last char.
I modified your code now try this:

```
$values = mysql_query("SELECT Pointer AS Pointer, VNum AS Vnum FROM ".$table."");
$row = 0;
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_assoc($values)) 
{
  foreach($rowr as $name => $value)
  {
      $csv_output .= $value."|";
  }
      $csv_output = substr_replace($csv_output ,"",-1); //these will remove the excess char

      $csv_output .= "\n";
}
```

Comment: And _this_ answer is the accepted answer?! omg: concatenating, only to remove it afterwards?  you can get the same result with a single line of code!

Answer (score 2):

When I do stuff like that, I make an array, then do a join - it puts the delimiter only in between, not at the end.

```
$arr = array();
foreach($rowr as $name => $value)
{
      $arr[] = $value;
}
$csv_output = join('|',$arr);
```

Comment: Do be aware that the `join` is likely to be deprecated some time soon. It's an alias for `implode`, just like `split` was to `explode`. The latter has been officially deprecated, I would't be surprized if `join` were to follow suite.

Comment: There is no indication of that in the documentation, so who knows.

Comment: Just spend some time browsing the developers' mailing list: They talk about _removing_ the `mysql_*` extension in PHP6, which _could_ be the next release after 5.5. Also: PHP get's a lot of slack for its vast global namespace. The first functions to go, IMO, should be those that aren't used too often... (like `join`, I'm afraid). I didn't down-vote your answer because it's a valid one. I just felt that it was something that you might want to take into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just implode the array:

```
$csv_output .= implode('|', $rowr)."\n";
```

That should give you the desired result.

Please, do be aware that the `mysql_*` extension is being deprecated, and should not be used to write new code. Look into `PDO` and/or `mysqli_*`. The the `i` stands for *improved*.

The *"full"* while loop ends up looking like this:

```
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_assoc($values))
{
    $csv_output .= implode('|', $rowr)."\n";
}
```

OR, you can write the data to a csv directly (with custom delimiter):

```
$handle = fopen('mycsv.csv','w+');
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_assoc($values))
{
    fputcsv($handle, $rowr, '|');
}
fclose($handle);
```

And that's it: your file is created, and contains all data. Check the docs for more info on the [fputcsv function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$values = mysql_query("SELECT Pointer AS Pointer, VNum AS Vnum FROM ".$table."");
$row = 0;
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_assoc($values)) {
  $csv_output .= implode('|', $rowr) . "\n";
}
```

Also, stop using mysql_* functions, blah blah PDO blah MySQLi.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
$csvArray = array();
foreach ($rowr as $name => $value) {
    $csvArray[] = $value;
}
$csv_output = implode('|', $csvArray);
```

Comment: This will *still* leave a trailing pipe, and double-pipe where the rows join.

Comment: @Sammitch my bad, fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
$values = mysql_query("SELECT Pointer AS Pointer, VNum AS Vnum FROM ".$table."");
$row = 0;
$csv_output = '';
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_assoc($values)) 
{
  foreach($rowr as $name => $value)
  {
      $csv_output .= $value."|";
  }
  $csv_output .= substr($csv_output, 0, -1) . "\n";
  // we subtract one char at the end
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to see if the $value you are gonna print is the last one or not and add the character only when is not the last one.

```
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_assoc($values)) 
{
  $last = rowr[count($rowr)-1];
  foreach($rowr as $name => $value)
  {
      $csv_output .= $value;
      if($last != $value){
          echo "|";
      }
  }
      $csv_output .= "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it directly on `MySQL` so you won't have any concatenation on your PHP code?  
In `MySQL` use the built-in function `GROUP_CONCAT`,

example record,

```
columnName
===========
1
2
3
4
5
```

query,

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(columnName SEPARATOR '|') lists
FROM   TableName
```

Result,

```
Lists
=========
1|2|3|4|5
```

- [GROUP_CONCAT() <sup>MySQL Docs</sup>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 0):

$csv_output = rtrim($csv_output, '|');